# Cant run any npm install

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

when i try to run npm install @ionic/pwa-elements for my ionic angular project, its keep to show this error

```
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! syscall link
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\e88430fb
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\95\c4\24053a363eb6ed04467d82d134dd3cba10d1b820aa0af9794b40c5b988e055001ac2515c13a8d18ee806e352e57c739cbd28463eab508cbbc3552e390bd1
npm ERR! errno ENOTSUP
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular: ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, link 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\e88430fb' -> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\95\c4\24053a363eb6ed04467d82d134dd3cba10d1b820aa0af9794b40c5b988e055001ac2515c13a8d18ee806e352e57c739cbd28463eab508cbbc3552e390bd1'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-28T02_57_25_718Z-debug-0.log
```

then, i tried to clear cache and run npm cache ls and npm cache verify to make sure i clear all the cache, delete my node-module and package-lock.json, i still got the same error when i run npm install

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's a npm cache problem.

You said that you tried to remove cache (`npm cache clean --force`), right?

You can also try to update npm:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

If the error is still there, you can try deleting the entire npm cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.npm
```